# How do I validate a boot partition in Linux?

Tags: linux, raid, bootloader, boot-partition

I have a Linux machine with two SSD drives as its main drive. While installing Ubuntu 20 or CentOS 8, I partitioned the drives each with a 2g boot partition and the rest as a root partition, then used MDADM to raid them together as raid1.

They appear to have the same content, but I can only directly boot off of one of them. Booting fails when I direct the boot loader to the other drive. Is there a diagnostic tool I can use to identify why I can't boot to the other drive?

Comment: `Booting fails when I direct the boot loader to the other drive` → Please provide boot log or error message

Comment: There is no boot log. All i get when I attempt to boot to that disk is a cursor flashing on a blank screen.